# Why am I having an syntax error in my query near "WHERE"? (Multiple tables)

Tags: java, jquery, cursor, left-join, multiple-tables

Im still new on this and it's my first time using these multiple tables query. Why am I having such an error? Here is my Code:

```
 String selectQuery =
            " select *" +
            "    from tableassign left outer join\n" +
            "         tableacc\n" +
            "         on tableassign.signeeid = tableacc.userid left outer join\n" +
            "         tableinfo\n" +
            "         on tableassign.signeeid = tableinfo.userid left outer join\n" +
                    " WHERE tableassign.signeedepid =?";
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(selectQuery , new String[]{ signeedep });
```

Error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "WHERE": syntax error (code 1):
 , while compiling: select *  from tableassign left outer join  tableacc on
 tableassign.signeeid = tableacc.userid left outer join  tableinfo on 
tableassign.signeeid = tableinfo.userid left outer join WHERE 
tableassign.signeedepid =?
```

Comment: Try removing the last "left outer join"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have a copy/paste issue. remove the last `left outer join` before `where`:

```
String selectQuery =
        " select *" +
        "    from tableassign left outer join\n" +
        "         tableacc\n" +
        "         on tableassign.signeeid = tableacc.userid left outer join\n" +
        "         tableinfo\n" +
        "         on tableassign.signeeid = tableinfo.userid\n" +
                " WHERE tableassign.signeedepid =?";
Cursor data = db.rawQuery(selectQuery , new String[]{ signeedep });
```

And I would format it a bit differently, mainly for readability:

```
String selectQuery =
        " SELECT *\n" +
        " FROM tableassign\n" +
        " LEFT JOIN tableacc ON tableassign.signeeid = tableacc.userid\n" +
        " LEFT JOIN tableinfo ON tableassign.signeeid = tableinfo.userid\n" +
        " WHERE tableassign.signeedepid =?";
Cursor data = db.rawQuery(selectQuery , new String[]{ signeedep });
```

Answer (score 1):

While I am unsure exactly what structured language you are using for the queries, the problem appears to be with your use of the JOIN operator. The Oracle documentation on [LEFT OUTER JOIN](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj18922.html) shows the correct usage of it, in which the syntax is:

```
TableExpression LEFT [ OUTER ] JOIN TableExpression
{
    ON booleanExpression |
    USING clause
}
```

The final LEFT OUTER JOIN immediately precedes the WHERE clause without defining a TableExpression. Remove the LEFT OUTER JOIN clause to remove the error.

```
 String selectQuery =
            " select *" +
            "    from tableassign left outer join\n" +
            "         tableacc\n" +
            "         on tableassign.signeeid = tableacc.userid left outer join\n" +
            "         tableinfo\n" +
            "         on tableassign.signeeid = tableinfo.userid" +
                    " WHERE tableassign.signeedepid =?";
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(selectQuery , new String[]{ signeedep });
```